# start-process issue with json contents

Tags: json, powershell

Contents of .js file. Program.js

```
[
        { "ProgramName":"Chrome", "FilePath":"\"\\\\PCNAME\\c$\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\Work Notes\\Programs\\Google\\ChromeSetup.exe\""},
        { "ProgramName":"Notepad ++", "FilePath":"\"\\\\PCNAME\\c$\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\Work Notes\\Programs\\Notepad ++\\npp.7.3.3.Installer.exe\"" }

    ]
```

I'm bad at explaining but I'm trying to get the `ProgramName` for each line of the json file and if the name matches one of the names in the `$computernames` array. Then use the corresponding `FilePath` of the `programname` to run the installer.
This is what I have so far.

```
$json = (Get-Content "\\PCNAME\c$\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Powershell\SCCM\Softwareinstaller\Program.js" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
$computerNames = "Chrome","Office","Google Earth","Adobe Pro","GoToMeeting Opener"
foreach ($thing in $json) 
{
    foreach ($thing2 in $json)
    {
        if ($computernames -contains $Thing2.programname)
        {
            Start-Process -filepath $thing.FilePath -wait
        }
    }

}
```

I plan on adding more to the json file so a method that doesn't look for just the line number would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have the `thing2`-loop. Your JSON is an array of items. Run a loop, see if the name is in your `$computerNames`-array (bad name btw.) and execute. Try:

```
$json = (Get-Content "\\PCNAME\c$\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Powershell\SCCM\Softwareinstaller\Program.js" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
$computerNames = "Chrome","Office","Google Earth","Adobe Pro","GoToMeeting Opener"

foreach ($thing in $json) 
{
    if ($computernames -contains $thing.ProgramName)
    {
        Start-Process -FilePath $thing.FilePath -wait
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah, I should have cleared up the array name. Thank you this solved my problem